# I am a genius. Find out who am I

Tags: riddle, knowledge, literature

I am a genius.

You all miss me

I specialise in Mathematics and crime. A deadly combination, isn't it?

People consult me for both.

I have only one nemesis of my level of intelligence.

He destroyed my reputation.

But, Don't worry, I will be back soon.

In the mean time, Can you guess Who am I?

Comment: This isn't really a riddle, is it? It's just trivia - not a puzzle.

Comment: I've downvoted this question because I think it follows a pattern that doesn't lend itself very well to high-interest riddles - primarily, it relies solely on recognizing an idea by a few aspects of it that have been alluded to in individual lines. Riddles of this type tend to be straightforward to solve by recognition and prior knowledge alone, rather than pushing the reader for metaphorical reasoning.

Comment: All right moderators, I would take care in the future... Would publish a better one next time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty much credit to dcfyj, but the actual answer is:

> Professor Moriarty

I am a genius.

> He was a criminal mastermind and professor of mathematics who ran crime all across Europe due to his adeptness.

You all miss me

> no one suspected such an esteemed professor. author's idea- BBC's Sherlock season 4 teaser starts with Moriarty-saying "Miss me?"

I specialise in Mathematics and crime. A deadly combination, isn't it?

> As said above criminal mastermind and math prof. Also moriarty has roots that mean death so possible wordplay

People consult me for both.

> He gives guidance to criminals, and well that is sort of a professor's job

I have only one nemesis of my level of intelligence.

> Holmes

He destroyed my reputation.

> Holmes did indeed foil Moriarty in the end.

But, Don't worry, I will be back soon.

> less concrete but the fall which allegedly killed Holmes and Moriarty did not kill Holmes so... Alternatively, more stories were written involving Moriarty after the death story (previous to it chronologically). So he did come back.
> Author's idea- Moriarty is back in Sherlock season 4 after apparently killing himself in Season 2.

Comment: Yeah.. that's right, explain the penultimate line and I will accept the answer.

Comment: Not what I had in my mind. Look at the tags, and think it through. Remember, "It;s not the fall that kills you, it's the landing"

Comment: This makes me sad, right idea, wrong person lol

Comment: @dcfyj Yeah.. it had to be one of the two(Were there any other options?). you chose the wrong one.

Comment: Latest guess up; however, I don't think I am going to get exactly what you are aiming for.

Comment: I will accept this.. and edit your answer..

Answer (score 4):

This offhand makes me think of

> Sherlock Holmes

but I'm not sure how to apply that to all the lines so here are the ones I can think of at the moment:

I am a genius.

> He is, simple fact.

You all miss me

> Perhaps because he faked his death?

I specialise in Mathematics and crime. A deadly combination, isn't it?

> I'm not sure about this one.

People consult me for both.

> He's a consultant.

I have only one nemesis of my level of intelligence.

> Moriarty

He destroyed my reputation.

> In an effort to outsmart Holmes he destroyed his reputation. (I forget the details but I believe he did this by having people believe that Holmes had wrongly accused him of a crime which there by put all of his cases under question.)

But, Don't worry, I will be back soon.

> Sherlock faked his death in order to beat Moriarty with the intention of coming back eventually.

In the mean time, Can you guess Who am I?

Comment: Close. Think a little more and the other way round...

Answer (score 1):

I think

> Logic

I am a genius.

> The logic is a genius.

You all miss me

> Everyone use the logic also without think to it.

I specialise in Mathematics and crime. A deadly combination, isn't it?

> The logic works good with Math and Critical Thinking.

People consult me for both.

> When you do math and you solve a crime you use the logic.

I have only one nemesis of my level of intelligence.

> I think it's an anagram, Nemesis was a spirit in **Mythology** -> Logy -> Logic.

He destroyed my reputation.

> Sometimes some genius like Stephen Hawking have some problems (like immobility), and It destroys the reputation a few, but...

But, Don't worry, I will be back soon.

> They are genius and they study the world.